# Billing Enabled for Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create an instance but I keep getting the error of billing must be enabled.  I have enabled billing and I gave it several hours and I am still having the same issue.  Project Number: 375741478

Comment: Can you go to https://console.developers.google.com/project/375741478/apiui/api and ensure that 'Google Cloud SQL' is turned on and then try and create an instance.